# System Monitor reports different memory usage to htop - which should I believe?

Tags: memory-usage

I've used both the preinstalled System Monitor and the htop app in Ubuntu and I've noticed differences in their outputs - the first shows higher memory usage. Which one is more accurate? Thanks.

Comment: Possible reasons for different values could be rounding differences, GB (base 1000) vs GiB (base 1024), treating some usage types (like shared memory, buffers, caches, ...) differently, etc. When in doubt, I would look at the output of `free` and trust that.

Comment: All are accurate, as they all read data from `/proc/meminfo`. You have to learn what those numbers mean to understand the difference.

Comment: also see https://www.linuxatemyram.com/